# How to fix "error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base"?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

When I execute the following command:

```
pip2 install -r requirements.txt --upgrade --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --install-option=--prefix= --target /home/peng/git/datapassports/spookystuff/uav/target/classes/python
```

I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py:212: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting dronekit from git+https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python.git@ed132c#egg=dronekit (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Cloning https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python.git (to ed132c) to /tmp/pip-build-p2lVND/dronekit
  Could not find a tag or branch 'ed132c', assuming commit.
Collecting dronekit-sitl==3.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/ff/967e87ac5ac09cea5cdb5bbca5b48a24f695d6e583deb26f7ecf491fb884/dronekit_sitl-3.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting future==0.17.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/52/e20466b85000a181e1e144fd8305caf2cf475e2f9674e797b222f8105f5f/future-0.17.1.tar.gz
Collecting lxml==4.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/4a/b085a04d6dad79aa5c00c65c9b2bbcb2c6c22e5ac341e7968e0ad2c57e2f/lxml-4.3.0.tar.gz
Collecting mavproxy==1.6.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/be/0ecacae8e949ba2fe800c544108a1a66e814ed53e44fee5cfd2c376ccd03/MAVProxy-1.6.4.tar.gz
Collecting monotonic==1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/c1/27f722aaaaf98786a1b338b78cf60960d9fe4849825b071f4e300da29589/monotonic-1.5.tar.gz
Collecting psutil==5.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/a0/833bcbcede5141cc5615e50c7cc5b960ce93d9c9b885fbe3b7d36e48a2d4/psutil-5.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting pymavlink==2.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/d7/a3b2e6e2d7bffd2d5426359111a2d90c9b13ca3148eec1aed9fffa639f5e/pymavlink-2.3.4.tar.gz
Collecting pyserial==3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/74/11b04703ec416717b247d789103277269d567db575d2fd88f25d9767fe3d/pyserial-3.4.tar.gz
Collecting simplejson==3.16.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/24/c35fb1c1c315fc0fffe61ea00d3f88e85469004713dab488dee4f35b0aff/simplejson-3.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting six==1.12.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/bf/4138e7bfb757de47d1f4b6994648ec67a51efe58fa907c1e11e350cddfca/six-1.12.0.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for dronekit-sitl, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for future, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for lxml, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for mavproxy, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for monotonic, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for psutil, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for pymavlink, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for pyserial, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for simplejson, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for six, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: future, monotonic, lxml, pymavlink, dronekit, psutil, six, dronekit-sitl, pyserial, mavproxy, simplejson
  Running setup.py install for future: started
    Running setup.py install for future: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-p2lVND/future/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ymI1OI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --prefix= --user --prefix= --home=/tmp/tmpEs6GmF:
    running install
    error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base
```

What does this error message mean? And how to fix it?

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and python 2.7. Due to python2 system dependencies being directly managed by linux package manager (apt), I cannot run pip install as root user.

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong:

```
 --install-option=--prefix=
```

The syntax should be like:

```
 --install-option="--prefix='/usr/local'"
```

However, that's kind of irrelevant, you don't need root access,  install pip packages with:

```
pip2 install -r requirements.txt --user
```